# Integrating (floor(x) e^-x) from 0 to inf

Tags: calculus, gre-exam

How does one obtain the following result:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \text{floor}(x) e^{-x} dx= \frac{1}{e-1}
\end{equation}

where $\text{floor}(x)$ is the greatest integer not exceeding x (from practice booklet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the nature of the floor function, the integral becomes a sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \int_{k}^{k+1} dx \, e^{-x}  = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \left (e^{-k}-e^{-(k+1)}\right ) $$

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \, e^{-k}= -\left [\frac{d}{da} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-a k} \right ]_{a=1}= -\left [\frac{d}{da} \frac1{1-e^{-a}}\right ]_{a=1} = \frac{e}{(e-1)^2}$$

Therefore, the integral is

$$\frac{e}{(e-1)^2} - \frac1{e} \frac{e}{(e-1)^2} = \frac1{e-1} $$

Comment: Are you sure differentiation across the sum in this manner is legal? I'm getting a different answer:

Comment: @DFord: yes, absolutely certain.  Why would it not be valid?

Comment: Because the validity of term-by-term differentiation of an infinite series is a subtle and nontrivial question; there are lots of function series for which term-by-term differentiation does not result in the derivative of the limiting function, due to uniform convergence issues. In particular, $f(x) = (1-x)^{-1}$ is not uniformly continuous on $(1, \infty)$.

Comment: \begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\left(e^{-k}-e^{-k-1}\right) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n k\left(e^{-k}-e^{-k-1}\right) \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \bigg(\left(e^{-1}-e^{-2}\right) + 2\left(e^{-2}-e^{-3}\right)+3\left(e^{-3}-e^{-4}\right) + \cdots + n\left(e^{-n}-e^{-n-1}\right)\bigg) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-k} + ne^{-n-1}\right) = \frac{e}{e-1}+0 = \frac{e}{e-1}
\end{align*}
Am I in error in my calculation?

Comment: @DFord: while I cannot disagree in general, in this particular case your concern is unwarranted.  And BTW I have no idea how you came to the third line from the second.

Comment: @DFord: one other thing: the result on the RHS is correct and may be derived in several different ways.  For example:
$$S = x+2 x^2+3 x^3 + 4 x^4 + ...$$
$$x S = x^2 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^4 + ...$$
$$(1-x) S = x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 +... = \frac{x}{1-x}$$
$$ S = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} $$

Comment: You mean this one? 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\left(e^{-k}-e^{-k-1}\right) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg(\left(e^{-1}-e^{-2}\right) + 2\left(e^{-2}-e^{-3}\right) + 3\left(e^{-3}-e^{-4}\right)+\cdots + n\left(e^{-n}-e^{-n-1}\right)\bigg) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(e^{-1}+2e^{-2}-e^{-2}+3e^{-3}-2e^{-3}+\cdots+ne^{-n}-(n-1)e^{-n} - ne^{-n-1} \bigg) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(-ne^{-n-1}+\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-k}\right)
\end{align*}
Admittedly I missed a $-$ sign.

Comment: @DFord: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-k} = \frac{e^{-1}}{1-e^{-1}} = \frac1{e-1}$$

Comment: Aha. I see my error. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1:** Note that on $[n,n+1)$, the expression $\lfloor x\rfloor e^{-x}$ equals $ne^{-x}$.

**Hint 2:** You can also write $\displaystyle{\int_0^Nf(x)\;dx = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\int_n^{n+1}f(x)\;dx}$